# MariaDB chokes on lock file after forced docker restart

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a docker compose setup for running Nextcloud alongside a MariaDB container and a reverse proxy etc. Recently, I had to force a manual restart of the docker daemon because some containers were stuck after an update & could not be terminated cleanly. Now my MariaDB does not start anymore.

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
[Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

This is kind of an obvious catch, the service had no chance to remove its lockfile when it was unconditionally terminated. When I now mv the ibdata file to a backup location, I see a whole stream of other errors:

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
[Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
[Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
[Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
[Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: redo log file './ib_logfile0' exists. Creating system tablespace with existing redo log file is not recommended. Please delete redo log file before creating new system tablespace.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

I'm out of my wits at this point. What do have to I have to do in order to start my container? I ran into a similar problem with a MongoDB container which booted fine after just dumping the lock file.

Answer (score 0):

`ibdata1` isn't a lock file, its the system tablespace that was getting a filesystem lock on it so that it was exclusive use.

Since you've deleted this you'll need to restore from your backup.

The unable to obtain lock on this file is a very reliable indicator that another mariadb process was already running on that data directory and system tablespace.

The correct action was to identify the other instance and stop it. Even uncleanly stopped mariadb processes/containers would relinquish the lock as its a lock that is held in the Linux kernel that gets removed when the process dies.

Comment: Luckily, I didn't delete anything, but renamed some files so they're still there. :) I am practically 100% sure that there never was a second process touching the files in question because I haven't even installed mysql/mariadb on the system, I only run it by starting a container. The mariadb-container terminates almost instantly after hitting the problem, which makes it even more unlikely that there would have been a second one at any time. Which means there is no other process to reclaim the lock from.

Comment: Test with `lsof /volumne-original...datadir/ibdata1` from the host.  Also check process list. The first instance won't terminate immediately because it has the exclusive lock.